# Rails: Simple_form on one line?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am making a form with simple_form, and I'm trying to get all inputs on the same line (I want all elements to be inline horizontally on the rendered page).

I have googled the problem for some hours, but I couldn't find a solution that works.

The simple_form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, :html => {:class => 'form-inline' }) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :link, label: false, placeholder: "here..." %>
   <%= f.input :type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-on icon-white"></i></span>'.html_safe, '0'], ['<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i></span>'.html_safe, '1'], ['<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-on icon-white"></i> + <i class="icon-of icon-white"></i></span>'.html_safe, '2']], item_wrapper_class: 'inline', label: false %>
   <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-inverse") do %>
      <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want it all elements to be inline horizontally on the rendered page?

Comment: What do you mean by 'to get all inputs on the same line'. Is in terms of UI to display all the fields together?

Comment: Yes, I want all elements to be inline horizontally on the rendered page.

Comment: @allegutta this is more of a CSS question. I've added the tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple_form creates a form containing a div for each input.
Each div contains a label and an input field

so your css should look like:

```
.form-inline div { display: inline-block }
```

Comment: sorted out my problem too.